# Comparing inputfile lines to the elements of a for-loop array

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop, while-loop

GOAL: Compare each line ("string") of a inputfile to an associative array composed of strings.

```
function watchlist ()
{
        declare -A flagged_ip # static arr. holds suspect ipaddr's
        while read -r ipaddr
        do
                for y in "${RA[labl]}" 
                do
                        if [ "$ipaddr" == "$y" ]
                        then
                                # setup arr. to hold all matching ipaddr(s)
                                flagged_ip+=( $ipaddr )
                        fi
                done
        done < "$ipfile"  # txt ipfile composed of designated ip's 
}
```

ISSUE: Currrently the output of the comparison from the function is blank. The "while-loop" seems to be correctly running but the "for-loop" seems to not be handling the comparison correctly.

ADDIT. DETAILS: The purpose of the function is to take an inputfile (composed of known ip's) provided by the user and compare them to an array of access-log ip's. Finally, I would like to pass each match of the comparison into an array then print the array so the user can see which items were successful matches.

My apologies for any bad or informal english

Comment: Change `"$ipaddr" == "$y"` to `"$ipaddr" = "$y"`.

Comment: I made the change &  I understand why you suggested it (thank you) but I still seem to keep getting a blank output when doing ```echo "${flagged_ip[@]} " ```

Comment: Do you actually call `watchlist` anywhere in your script?

Comment: My fault bruv needed to to make some changes to ```$ipfile``` value, its on me not you. Made some mods specifically ```ipfile="$(cat "${@: -1}")"```. Thank you all the same the string comparison was incorrect I realize that now

Comment: What is `labl` in your function? If it is a variable it should be `$labl`. Where is it set/incremented?

Comment: ```labl``` represents the ip address in the access logs

Comment: Sure, but if it's a variable it should be changed/incremented inside the loop, and it should have a `$` when it is referenced.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to loop through all elements, replace `labl` with `@`

```
for y in "${RA[@]}"
```

You can also consider using something like

```
grep -xf <(printf "%s\n" ${RA[@]}) "$ipfile"
```

and store it in an array with

```
flagged_ip=($(grep -xf <(printf "%s\n" ${RA[@]}) "$ipfile"))
```